# Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04

Can you help me?
My ubuntu 22.04 is working well, but all start begins with the message:
Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables

Based on earlier similar questions, ( in case of Ubuntu 16)
the message is different.
What should I do?

`sudo systemctl status systemd-sysctl.service`

```
systemd-sysctl.service - Apply Kernel Variables
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-sysctl.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-17 10:05:08 CET; 6min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysctl.service(8)
             man:sysctl.d(5)
    Process: 1290 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1290 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 4ms

dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd-sysctl[1290]: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:61: Line is not an assignment, ignoring: cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd-sysctl[1290]: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:62: Line is not an assignment, ignoring: sudo fstrim -v /
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd-sysctl[1290]: /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:64: Line is not an assignment, ignoring: cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd-sysctl[1290]: Couldn't write '1' to 'kernel/unprivileged_userns_clone', ignoring: No such file or directory
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd[1]: systemd-sysctl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dec 17 10:05:08 brs-H97M-HD3 systemd[1]: Failed to start Apply Kernel Variables.
```

Comment: Remove what you added to `/etc/sysctl.conf`, [edit] its contents into this question if unsure.  It's not a shell script.